# What is the function of 'Affinities' in Marketing Cloud Personalization Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein, einstein-recommendations

In Marketing Cloud Personalization Builder -> Web Recommendations->Reporting->Contacts
When I check a Profile using Email id I can see 'Affinities'?
How do I use these Affinities for my Web/Email Recommendations or are these 'Affinities' used in the Recommendations by default and how?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can answer this with a kind of mixed feeling because some aspects are not really documented but were told me on different occasions:

There is a recommendation scenario named "User Affinities" which will automaticly select one of the highest rated categories/tags for that user. This is the best purpose i could find to use these metrics. This scenario is not shown in the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_pb_einstein_recommendation_scenarios.htm&type=5) but will appear under the dropdown of scenarios

On the other hand it can give you some insight on particular customers if you want to know how these people actually behave. But i have not found a documented api to receive the data shown in your screenshots. It could be nice to store it as attributes in your crm or stuff like that.

Rumor:
The user affinities seem to effect the regular recommendations to a certain extend. Since the recommendation engine tries to change products that you will not always see the same products it may take these values into account and boosts according to user affinities. This is not documented and is also a kind of "rumor", you won't find ressources to this and i am not even sure it is correct.